# How to pass pairs of numbers from one array to another array

Tags: java

> I try to move pairs numbers from one array to other.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tamanio, cont_p=0;
    
    tamanio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de números a ingresar: "));
    int [] arreglo = new int[tamanio];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        arreglo[i]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el número "+(i+1)+": "));
        System.out.print(arreglo[i]+", ");
        if(arreglo[i]%2==0){
            cont_p++;
        }
    }
    
    int [] contenedorpares = new int[cont_p];
    cont_p=0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < contenedorpares.length; i++) {
        if(arreglo[i]%2==0){
            contenedorpares[cont_p]=arreglo[i];
        }
        System.out.println(contenedorpares[i]+", ");
    }
}
```

> When the program run, show this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have set the cont_p as zero and
You are not incrementing cont_p after doing this
`contenedorpares[cont_p]=arreglo[<br/>];`

Do `cont_p++` once you add an element

Comment: Ok, I'll try, bro